# app is not getting uninstalled from device

Tags: android, android-studio, uninstallation

I used my mobile for testing of android application.
I used to run application directly from android studio.

now the app is not getting uninstalled, if I am trying to uninstall the app It finishes the task successfully but in app manager it shows **"not installed"**
[image: see the list of apps]

[image: APP details after performing uninstall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the top-right corner button, you will see an option `Uninstall for all users` and click on same, this will uninstall the app completely.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me once..restarting the phone did the trick for me.